# Is SSL for WCF needed when using Transport Security?

Tags: .net, wcf

OK I am probably getting too far in the weeds with my WCF configuration and can't see the forest through the trees, so I want to checkpoint on security.

I have (2) bindings exposed in a WCF service for options on the client side consuming: netTcpBinding and wsHttpBinding (both fine and working). I have both configured with the default: clientCredentialType="Windows". I have the wsHttpBinding configured to use a SSL certificate and expose the endpoint via https (I want this), and also have an SSL cert configured for the netTcpBinding to use SSL over TCP (I want this too).

Here is where I keep getting mixed information. Apparently "Transport" security is inheriently secure. Does this mean I do *not* need a SSL cert then if I want to secure the Transport layer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to do a lot of reading between multiple articles to get the details I was looking for from my original post. The information that helped things to clear up a bit for me was the following:

*Each protocol (TCP, HTTP, MSMQ, NamedPipes) has its own mechanism for passing credentials and handling message protection.*

Above is from the [WCFSecurityGuide](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/15892)

Coming from a primarily web background I have a pretty good understanding of HTTP and securing it with a SSL cert. However this exact procedure is not required in a Windows environment for net.tcp which uses its own method in Windows to secure the transport layer.

So when it gets down to it, here are the (2) explinations in regards to securing a HTTP binding and net.tcp in a Windows environment that I wanted to understand:

**For net.tcp:**  *The service and clients are authenticated using Windows authentication, and the messages are secured at the transport level by Windows security*

**For a HTTP binding (i.e. wsHttpBinding):** *When using HTTP bindings, the transport security is provided by SSL. The SSL certificate is used to provide the message protection.*

So I will *not* need a SSL cert for the net.tcp binding as that is handled by Windows Security and is inheriently secure when using Transport security. When using a wsHttpBinding I will still need to secure the Transport with a SSL certificate which I had done as mentioned previously, and exposed the binding via HTTPS.

If any future readers have similar questions the WCF guide link I posted and the link below are a good place to start:

**Common WCF Security Scenarios:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730301.aspx

Comment: Good summary! Just to be ulta-clear, "message protection" for this configuration means an encrypted channel (the transport) is established through which the message is transmitted to the service. The message itself is **not** encrypted and doesn't need to be since the channel is secure. WCF also has message level security (which is **not** enabled in this configuration) that encrypts the message itself so it can transmitted over unsecure channels or passed through intermediaries with compromising the contents of the message.

Comment: Thanks! Some info from the WCFSecurityGuid (p.127) to elaborate more about security modes and their description: **None**: No security is provided; you should not use this option. **Transport**: Mutual authentication and message protection are provided at the transport level. **Message**: Mutual authentication and message protection are provided at the message level. **Both**: Mutual authentication and message protection are provided at both the transport and message level. This is far more than is needed for most scenarios.

Comment: cont... **TransportWithMessageCredential**: Client authentication is provided at the message level, and message protection and service authentication are provided at the transport level.
**TransportCredentialOnly**: Mutual authentication is provided at the transport level, but no message protection is provided.

Comment: @SixtoSaez just to ultra-ultra-clarify: does this mean that a hacker who spoofs (or gets hold of) a Windows authentication can read, and potentially alter, the message traffic between client and service?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed this today.Yes, absolutely, they can alter the message. You're describing the classic 'man in the middle' (MITM) compromise. Encrypting at the message level mitigates against MITM attacks. Message level encryption is independent from transport channel encryption so you could apply both in WCF.

Answer (score 2):

In this setup, "Transport" security is how you tell WCF that you really want it to use SSL. In order for SSL to work you need a server certificate that the client can verify (either from a signing authority or a self-signed one that you install on the client).

So you've got it right. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I appreciate it. I am still a little confused (I read your response several times); so by being right I do *not* need a SSL cert because it is inherently secure or I do need it? I am trying to track down a good MSDN article (I have about 10 open right now) trying to explain Transport security and its relation to SSL for security in a Windows credential setup environment. I think I have all the links, still trying to understand if applying SSL (when security is desired) makes sense with my setup. Thanks!

Comment: I believe I am pretty clear on the wsHttpBinding. For securing the transport, you should use a configured SSL certificate to expose the binding via https. Done. And if this can be confirmed I am good with that. Where I am still confused is with the net.tcp binding. Some places I read security for this binding is offered by the OS (Security for the transport mode is provided by implementing Transport Layer Security (TLS) over TCP. The TLS implementation is provided by the operating system), and others say: for TCP, it is SSL over TCP or Windows. So still some confusion on the net.tcp binding.

Comment: You need a server certificate in order to use SSL. The certificate is how clients know the message they get from the server is REALLY from the server and wasn't intercepted and changed during transit. net.tcp is using TLS as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733089.aspx).

Comment: Yep that is the identically link I have been looking at this morning. I didn't read anything within it explaining 'TLS' specifically (Windows Security, Yes) but it was the source of the forumlated comments I made in my followup answer.